# USB WiFi adapter Compatibility

Tags: wireless, 14.04

Is there an actual list of compatible USB WiFi Adapters???  I have a Netgear WNA3100 that works for about 10 minutes then I have to restart the computer, I've looked everywhere and found nothing helpful, so my ony conclusion is it won't work!!!  I had a D-link card that worked fine in windows but when I got it working in linux the card died shortly thereafter and doesn't work anywhere now...  I want to know what I can buy off the shelf that works out of the box before I go spending more money!!!  I've been looking at a Linksys WUSB6300 from what I can find it has a Realtek chipset...

Comment: Check [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/402668/trouble-finding-ubuntu-compatable-usb-wifi-adapters).

Comment: Notice that buy recomendations are offtopic here, but you can search for specialized stores like http://thinkpenguin.com/

Comment: Personally i use a usb dongle with rtl8191 chipset. works like a charm even in brick buildings where i couldn't get any wifi signals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware recommendation question.

Answer (score 3):

FYI tested out of the box in Ubuntu 18.04/18.10 64bit

**WORKING:**
TP-Link TL-WN722N
TP-Link TL-WN821N
D-Link DWA-121
Panda

**NOT working:** 
Only tested on 15.04
Asus USB-N53
TP-Link Archer T2U (AC600)

I have not fiddled around or tried to install anything to make them work.

FYI There are still (2019) several USB WiFi adapters that doesn't work on Linux out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a list of some wireless cards that work with ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported), but there are many more, and almost anything you buy will be compatible with ubuntu.

Comment: That list is old, most of that hardware is no longer being produced...

Comment: Most new hardware work with ubuntu.

Comment: Or install the driver if it doesn't work.

Comment: Still in 2012 the drivers were not often available. That is the last time I used USB-wifi adapter, and had to return it to the store after discovering the chipset was not supported by kernel, and there were no drivers available. The adapter I got in exchange worked straight away out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Actually here's a solution that I'm currently using: Just use USB tethering with your mobile phone! Basically all mobile phones now have a WIFI adapter on its own which works perfectly well, and then through USB the data transmission rate is high. It's been working for me for a while.

Comment: Well, if you need it for your desktop computer / music server / NAS, don't you think using your 300 USD smartphone for the purpose is kind of expensive? Why not to use inexpensive 15 USD device which you can stick in the computer and leave there permanently?

Comment: @OssiViljakainen Apparently the original question asked exactly what to do when such a 15 USD device doesn't work. Here's something that is guaranteed to work.